# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')

Tags: react-native

I am getting value from shared preference, but when tried to store that value in this.state I am getting above error. I want to access business id globally so storing in this.state. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
this.state = {
  businessId: ""
};

SharedPreferences.getItem("business_entity_id",function(value){
  this.setState({businessId:value}).bind(this);

  console.log("val",this.state.businessId);
}); 

console.log("businessId for shared Preference:", this.state.businessId);
```

Comment: share your code more clearly

Comment: you can use a arrow function (value)=>{} in callback instead of function(value){}. you will get global "this" in the arrow function.

Comment: export default class MainCalendarScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var SharedPreferences = require('react-native-shared-preferences');

this.state = {
      bussinessId: ""
    };

    SharedPreferences.getItem("business_entity_id",function(value){
      this.setState({bussinessId:value}).bind(this);
      console.log("val",this.state.bussinessId);

    }); 
    console.log("bussinessId for shared Preference:",this.state.bussinessId);
}                      My Code

Comment: can you edit your question and add the code there? Also why are you binding your setstate?

Comment: How to use value out side of shared preference function? Exp: when I try to print value in console out of that function it shows undefined or empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrow function () => {} for function() {}, because when you use arrow function it will pass this into the function

```
this.state = {
  businessId: ""
};

SharedPreferences.getItem("business_entity_id",(value) => {
  this.setState({businessId:value}).bind(this);

  console.log("val",this.state.businessId);
}); 

console.log("businessId for shared Preference:", this.state.businessId);
```

Comment: value within the function is printing but how to use value out side of shared preference function? Exp: when I try to print value in console like this  console.log("businessId for shared Preference:", this.state.businessId);   out of that function it shows undefined or empty

Answer (score 0):

Is your code inside a `React.Component`? You cannot call it outside of `React.Component`.

This should work:

```
import React from "react";
import SharedPreferences from "react-native-shared-preferences";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      businessId: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    SharedPreferences.getItem("key", (value) => {
      this.setState({ businessId: value });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View></View>
    );
  }
}
```